# ggarrange and ggplot inside a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, plot, ggpubr

this is a simple example I have, where I generate 5 standard normals, each one with his own p value (just for the sake of the demonstration). I save that in a 4x50x5 array called X.

After that, I want to save 5 plots with 4 histograms each in a .pdf, and the following code does the job

```r
pvec <- 2^(2:5)
n <- pvec/2
j <- 5
size <- 50
X <- array(rep(NA, length(pvec)*reps*j), dim=c(length(pvec), reps, j))

for (k in 1:length(pvec)){
  for (i in 1:j){
    X[k,,i] <- rnorm(size)
  }
}

pdf("grafic.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (w in 1:j){
  for (k in 1:length(pvec)){
    hist(X[k,,w], freq = F, col = 'lightgreen',main = paste("p = ", pvec[k], ",n =", n[k]))
    curve(dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=1), add=TRUE,col="blue")
  }
}
dev.off()
```

Obtaining, for example

[image]

Let's say that I want to do this now, but with ggplot. I have to use ggarrange in replace of par(mfrow). But ggarrange uses a plot.list as an argument, so inside the for I should have something like

```r
graphlist <- NULL
for (w in 1:j){
  for (k in 1:length(p.vec)){
      graphlist[k,,w] <- ggplot(data=data.frame(X), aes(x=X[k,,w])) + 
        geom_histogram()
    }
}
ggarrange(plotlist = graphlist, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

But of course this doesn't work. How can I do stuffs like that, where I need to save the plots made by ggplot2 and then combine them with ggarrange? Thanks

Comment: Ggplot uses lazy evaluation, so if you switch to lapply, which uses forced evaluation, you may be ok. Is there a reason you can’t use facet_wrap?

Comment: Hello. Try to provide a reproducible code. I think you mixed `reps` and `size`.